# Umbraco - Regex OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, umbraco7

We're seeing a lot of these errors on an Umbraco 7 site:

```
ERROR Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase: An unhandled exception occurred
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at Go3761(RegexRunner )
at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexRunner.Scan(Regex regex, String text, Int32 textbeg, Int32 textend, Int32 textstart, Int32 prevlen, Boolean quick, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Run(Boolean quick, Int32 prevlen, String input, Int32 beginning, Int32 length, Int32 startat)
at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(String input, Int32 startat)
at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Database.AddSelectClause[T](String sql)
at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Database.<Query>d__7.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
at Umbraco.Core.Sync.DatabaseServerMessenger.ProcessDatabaseInstructions()
at Umbraco.Core.Sync.DatabaseServerMessenger.Sync()
at Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule.OnRouteAttempt(RoutableAttemptEventArgs args)
at Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Is this something anyone else has experienced? It doesn't seem to be a known Umbraco issue so it seems likely to be something to do with our specific setup - any pointers for how to track down the cause much appreciated. The stack trace above is all coming from Umbraco core code and we don't have direct control over the input to the regex.

Comment: Possibly the used regular expression is running out of memory while analyzing the value. This can happen with very long input or complex patterns.... I read something about it before... maybe I can find it

Comment: Here is something: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725817/outofmemoryexception-in-regex-matches-when-processing-large-files and it redirects to:  https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: @Stefan that looks to be the case. Problem is further up the stack is all Umbraco core code and I don't have any direct control over that

Comment: Do you have any control over the input value and/or regex being used? If not you should file a bug.

Comment: Sounds similar to this problem: https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/85597-systemoutofmemoryexception-in-umbracocoreumbracoapplicationbase

Comment: @Mark - thanks, it does look similar and we are running on Azure, though I don't see why changing the file attributes for a log file would have an effect, and we don't have any such log file on our setup.

Comment: @Stefan - no, AFAIK the entire stacktrace is all from Umbraco core code and we don't have any control over what goes into the regex call.

Comment: Okay, since it's an out of memory exception, the regex of umbraco might or might not be the cause of the issue. To determine if it is you can check the following things: 1) monitor general memory consumption: is it rising over time (this suggests a memory leak) 2) monitor memory consumption prior to the regex evaluation (it it high just before, e.g; are you processing memory intensive data, like multimedia, machine learning data, usage statistics etc) 3) does the exception always takes place at the same point, with the same stacktrace, same conditions? if not; the issue possibly lies elsewhere

Comment: @Stefan - it's always the same stack trace, 3 days running now at different times of day and no pattern I can see in the logs in terms of conditions leading up to it. That said, the server does do a fair bit of memory intensive work so I'll gather some more info about what's going on at the time the error occurs as you suggest & see if that sheds any light on it